# How to create a Pandas dataframe with multiindex columns with several level 0?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to construct a dataframe with multi indexes in columns. There must be two levels as in the example below (0 and 1), but with level 0 `route` assigned to columns 1 and 2, and level 0 `action` assigned to column 3.

How can I do that ?

In this example I'm able to assign level 0 `route` to columns 1, 2 and 3 :

```
indexes = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([['paris']], names=['name'])
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['route'], ['type', 'action src', 'action dst']], names=['first', 'second'])
df = pd.DataFrame([[2, 3, 4]], index=indexes, columns=columns)
df

first   route
second  type    action src  action dst
name            
paris   2   3   4
```

But the desired outpud is this :

```
first   route   action
second  type    source  destination
name            
paris   2   3   4
```

I'm not sure this question is well titled so feel free to give it a more appropriate title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html)

```py
import pandas as pd

indexes = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([['paris']], names=['name'])
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['route', 'action', 'action'], ['type', 'source', 'destination']], names=['first', 'second'])

df = pd.DataFrame([[2, 3, 4]], index=indexes, columns=columns)

print(df)
```

```
first  route action            
second  type source destination
name                           
paris      2      3           4
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays()`:

```
col = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['route', 'action', 'action'], ['type', 'source', 'destination']], names=['first', 'second'])
```

Finally:

```
df.columns=col
```

Now if you print `df` you will get your desired output:

```
first   route   action
second  type    source  destination
name            
paris   2           3       4
```